# Determine Sequence last used value for sql server before 2017

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I've got an issue with sql server before 2017. Its regarding current value and next value of a sequence.
In 2017 you can determine based on the `last_value_used` that `current_value` is the last value or the first following value. Lets say I increment with 1 then:
**If** `last_used_value = NULL` **then** `current_value` is the value returned with `NEXT VALUE FOR`.
**If** `last_used_value > 0` **then** `current_value + 1` is the value returned with `NEXT VALUE FOR`.

On Sql server 2016 I don't have the last_used_value. To illustrate I've got a small sql sample.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST START WITH 1
SELECT * FROM sys.sequences where name = 'SEQ_TEST';
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_TEST;
SELECT * FROM sys.sequences where name = 'SEQ_TEST';

+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
| name     | object_id | principal_id | schema_id | parent_object_id | type | start_value | increment | minimum_value | maximum_value | is_cycling | is_cached | cache_size | system_type_id | user_type_id | precision | scale | current_value | is_exhausted |
+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
| SEQ_TEST | 848036687 | NULL         | 73        | 0                | SO   | 1           | 1         | -9.22337E+18  | 9.22337E+18   | 0          | 1         | NULL       | 127            | 127          | 19        | 0     | 1             | 0            |
+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
| SEQ_TEST | 848036687 | NULL         | 73        | 0                | SO   | 1           | 1         | -9.22337E+18  | 9.22337E+18   | 0          | 1         | NULL       | 127            | 127          | 19        | 0     | 1             | 0            |
+----------+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+------+-------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------------+
```

Both selects from `sys.sequences` show the same data. So the question is: How do I determine what the last used value is of SEQ_TEST?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you care about this.  Normally you only care about the `NEXT VALUE`, as looking at the `current_value` is tricky with multiple sessions.

But you're essentially trying to determine if the sequence has been incremented.  So you can simply increment every sequence once after you create it.  EG

instead of

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST START WITH 1
```

use

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST START WITH 0
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_TEST
```

Comment: Why I care about it: I'm trying to make an administrative function of sorts where I evaluate if my sequence is still up to date with the field from my table. So I have a table `department` with a field `id` and a sequence `seq_department` for that field. When `max(id) == 5` and the last_used_value of seq_department isn't 5, I want to `restart with 6`. If current_value is higher than `start_with` I can assume that current_value is the last value used. but before that I can't